# Multiple column search then echo specific column(s) found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My MySQL database groups passenger names in vehicles involved in an "event."  Up to 46 firstname/lastname pairs can be dispersed among up to 5 vehicles in a single event (grouped as max of 2 in vehicle 1, 2 in vehicle 2, 4 in vehicle 3, 8 in vehicle 4, and 30 in vehicle 5). I can do a search of all 46 names and return the row id for each successful search. I then want to echo a list of hyperlinks of those successful searches so the user can click and see the entire record; however, for them to choose the row of interest, I need to show the name pair that caused their search to match.  Right now, since there are 46 columns for lastnames and 46 columns for firstnames, what it does is list only the first non-null firstname/lastname pair in the record.  So, it lists passenger 1 in vehicle 1 (whether it matched or not), rather than passengers 4 and 8 from vehicles 2 and 3 (which matched the search and were in the same record). These are all in one record because they have a common narrative about the event they were all involved in.

I've been successful in creating a numbered list of all records the search finds, and created a hyperlink for the date of the event.  Then, I attempted to echo additional columns after that hyperlink to identify the names involved so the user will know which link is most likely the one of interest.  As I mentioned, it returns only the first name pair in that record, not the name pair that the search found. Of course, if you click on the hyperlink, you get everything in that record, but that's a page later than where my problem is. I recognize that the loop is going through each record only once to create the row id, but I don't know how else to do that portion, if that's where it has to be edited. Or in the query, which is a multiple line iteration of this:

```
WHERE ((firstname1_1 IS NOT NULL and firstname1_1 LIKE '%$firstname%') AND (lastname1_1 IS NOT NULL and lastname1_1 LIKE '%$lastname%'))
OR ((firstname2_1 IS NOT NULL and firstname2_1 LIKE '%$firstname%') AND (lastname2_1 IS NOT NULL and lastname2_1 LIKE '%$lastname%'))
```

Here are a few lines of the code. Under the List Link portion, there should be 46 name pairs grouped in 5 vehicles, but I've truncated it here.

```
// Loop the recordset $result

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

// Lists results with the date being a hyperlink

$strName = $row['day_value'] . " " . $row['month_value'] . " " . $row['year_value'];

// Create a link to loss.php with the id-value in the URL

$strLink = "<a href = 'loss.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";

// List link; this outputs the first lastname of a record in the results

// array, rather than the lastname that was searched for, so that's the 

// problem.

print "<ol style='text-align: left;'>";

if(!empty('lastname1_1'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title1_1']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname1_1']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname1_1']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury1_1']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle1']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname2_1'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title2_1']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname2_1']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname2_1']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury2_1']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle1']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname1_2'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title1_2']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname1_2']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname1_2']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury1_2']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle2']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname2_2'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title2_2']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname2_2']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname2_2']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury2_2']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle2']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname1_3'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title1_3']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname1_3']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname1_3']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury1_3']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle3']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname2_3'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title2_3']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname2_3']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname2_3']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury2_3']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle3']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname3_3'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title3_3']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname3_3']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname3_3']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury3_3']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle3']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname4_3'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title4_3']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname4_3']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname4_3']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury4_3']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle3']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname1_4'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title1_4']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname1_4']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname1_4']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury1_4']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle4']}" . "</li>";

elseif(!empty('lastname2_4'))
echo "<li style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>" . $strLink . ":  " . "{$row['title2_4']}" . "  ". "{$row['firstname2_4']}" . "  " . "{$row['lastname2_4']}," . "  " . "{$row['injury2_4']}" . "  " . "{$row['vehicle4']}" . "</li>";

print "</ol";

}   
} 
// Close the database connection
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

I've been through a few dozen iterations trying to find a way to make it work.

I think, ideally, if there were a MySQL "LIKE" comparable in PHP, I might be able to use that in the list; however, if there is more than one name that matches the search in one record, that might still be a problem since I'd want to list all of those names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A) You really need to look into using loops. This kind of rampant repetition is not good. B) An inline string will never be empty. Do you mean `!empty($row['lastname2_4'])` instead? C) Having this many columns is a failure of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Let the relational database store *relational data*. This will largely eliminate most of your repetition here.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman, I appreciate the comments. It is unwieldy, most certainly, but if it works for my purposes then the only punishment is my own for having to copy, paste, and edit a lot of lines.  Clearly, I'm not an expert on this, and I don't get paid.  In building this, I started with a very simple search and built it as the database requirements grew.  So, when I had something that worked, I didn't go back and start over to make it prettier. My biggest concern about that is how long a search will take once the database is populated with a few thousand records.

Comment: @tadman, Changing to !empty($tow['lastname2_4']) doesn't change anything, and the original code did refuse to echo any line where the column was empty, that is, not part of the result array.  Of course I didn't put all of the code in the question, but I do have mysqli_real_escape_string for the $_POST of each input. I don't understand the reason for your note on mysqli vs mysql in relation to my question.  Please elaborate where it shows up in my code.  Thanks.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is *for exceptional circumstances only* and is not intended to be used for composing regular statements. That's what placeholder values and `bind_param` are for. You'll *will* forget to escape something and when you do, now you have a huge problem, there's zero protection at that point. Using placeholder values means you need to screw up a *bunch* of things before you're exposed.

Comment: Hint: `echo var_dump($row)` to see what data you're dealing with. Don't just expect to write a bunch of code and have it work. As a developer you need to work incrementally towards your goal, verifying each step before proceeding to the next. What I see here is a lot of untested code, you've gone way past what's working and made some wild assumptions about how it will come together. This should be trimmed down, refactored, and cleaned up before proceeding as you have way too much code here to maintain.

Comment: Hmmmm.  My searches work fine, and the hyperlinks work fine to deliver the complete data record that corresponds to the search that was conducted.  The only part that doesn't work like I want it to is what names are listed next to the hyperlink.  In other words, if I search for smith, but smith is the second passenger in a vehicle, what is echoed is the name of the first passenger in the vehicle.  How can I get the name of the person that was searched for presented in the list?

Comment: If you plan to maintain this, do yourself a huge favor and create a table of passengers, a table of events (with the narrative), and a table connecting them with vehicle info. However, to answer your direct question, if your goal is to echo back the information from the initial request, then you should just echo back the information from the original request, and not worry about getting that from the query.

Comment: @Jerry, if the original request is just a few letters as part of a name, without a query how can I echo the name that the query found? If someone searches for "smit," the query properly returns "smith," "smithson," and "goldsmith." I want to list each of those next to the hyperlink, even if they are all in the same record.

Comment: I still hope for an elegant solution; however, what I've decided to do is combine all last names for each row into a single column, then I echo that column after the hyperlink.  So, it lists all names for each of the events that are in the results of the search.  It's not perfect, but it will do until something better comes along.

Comment: Since you don't want to use a relational database to store relational data, I think the real answer to your question is "use a different type of database." Something like Mongo might fit your thought process better.

Comment: The database type can't be changed.